# Find the area bounded for $f(x)=x^2-4x$ and $x+y=0$

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the area bounded the following graph

$f(x)=x^2-4x$ and $x+y=0$

I'm not sure how to tackle this problem. The y is kind of throwing me off here. For other problems that I have been doing, there was no y. So I set both equation to equal eachother to solve for x to find the values to plug into the integration later on in the problem

Comment: When you say ``graph of $f(x) = x^2 - 4x$,'' you're implicitly assuming that $y = f(x)$, so try using that for the second equation as well.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Solving $y=x^2-4x$ and $y=-x$ we obtain $x=0$ or $x=3$

Required Area=$\int\limits_{0}^{3}(y_{\text{line}}-y_{\text{parabola}})dx= \int\limits_{0}^{3}(3x-x^2)dx$

Comment: I got the answer $\frac{9}{2}$ using  $dx= \int\limits_{0}^{3}(3x-x^2)dx$, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct.